# Value copy without using serialization in c#

Tags: c#, deep-copy, reference-type

I have two lists and I am trying to copy the source to the target. In the new iteration, changing the source affects the target. I understand, I am making a reference copy. Is there a way to make deep copy without using any serializer(due to performance issues). Please find my code below

```
public void ListFiller()
      {
         newListCopy = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>(newList);             
      }
```

Comment: what are source and target lists? You want to change source values and copy all values of source to target?

Comment: The Source is newList. And the target is newListCopy. I have to copy the newList into newListCopy and Input it into a dataGridView. For the next iteration the newList changes which changes the firstEntry of the dataGridview. That is the reason I need to copy the values not the reference

Comment: i would want the changes in newList in new iteration doesn't affect the newListCopy from last iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `KeyValuePair`s are structs and therefore will be recreated. However, the values of the `KeyValuePair` are not recreated because that are reference types. Therefore the same instance is still referenced in both data structures.

**The performant way** to solve that is to implement `IClonable` (or a custom clone method) and create a deep clone of your object manually. However that is time-consuming and you have to maintain the clone method if the object structure changes:

```
  public void ListFiller()
  {
     newListCopy = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
     foreach (var pair in newList)
     {
         var clone = (pair.Value as IClonable)?.Clone();
         // handle case that the object does not implement IClonable
         newListCopy.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(pair.Key, clone );
     }           
  }
```

As you already mentioned, **a simpler way** is, to use serialization for recreating the whole data structure. That is relativly easy to implement but not so performant (is that actually a problem?) and the objects need to be serializable.

The internet is full of [similar questions and solutions](https://www.google.de/search?biw=1440&bih=776&q=deep+clone+c%23&oq=deep+clone+c%23&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71k1l4.2960.3333.0.3430.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.5docWC9Tf-0).

Comment: Hi.. the object stucture is stable. And I have been using deep copy in earlier problems. I wanted to know whether there is a better solution. Let me try this and get back. Thanks.

Comment: I would add emphasis to "(is that actually a problem)". Usually hacks cost more than simple solutions. Do prefer simple to performance-optimized" unless you really have a performance problem.